# JavaScript order of operations - parentheses are not evaluated before post-increment operator

Tags: javascript, post-increment, operator-precedence

Example 1:

```
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
a = (b++);
console.log(a);
```

`a` is equal to `1` which is the same, with or without the parentheses. Example 2:

```
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
a = b++;
console.log(a);
```

I understand the second example.  `b` is assigned to `a`, then incremented to `2`.  But in the first example, why don't the parentheses force `b`  to increment to `2` before assigning the value to `a` given parentheses have the highest operator precedence?  Thanks.

Comment: Try `a = ++b;` instead. The increment will occur before the assignment

Comment: It got the highest `precedence`. [But both `Associativity` is `n/a`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation by T.J. is a good one on the theoretical level of what's going on, but here is another explanation from a different angle (more practical than theoretical):

We have two similar expressions `b++` and `++b`. Both mean `b = b + 1`, but they work differently.

`b++` evaluates to the current value of `b` (which is 1), then increments it. It's equivalent to:

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
a = b;
b = b + 1; //(b + 1) makes no difference
console.log(a);
```

`++b` does the opposite, increments `b`, then evaluates to the incremented value. It's equivalent to:

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
b = b + 1; //(b + 1) makes no difference
a = b;
console.log(a);
```

Now, notice that adding parentheses surround `b + 1` in any of the above examples will make no difference because the assignment `a = b` is done in a different step. Similarly, adding parentheses to `b++` will not make any difference because the assignment to `a` and the incrimination are done in two different steps.

However, the parentheses around `b++` are actually equivalent to parentheses around `b` on the line `a = b` in the code above, not around `b + 1` as you seem to think from your question. And it is clear that the parentheses `a = (b)` don't make any difference.

**EDIT** As you suggested in your comment, if we think of `b++` as an implicit function, then the body of the function is similar to T.J.'s explanation:

1. Save the value of `b` (1), let's say to an implicit variable `x`
2. Increment `b` to 2
3. and return `x`

Putting parentheses around the function call is like putting them around the returned value which is 1. Here is a demo:

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
a = bPlusPlus(); //(bPlusPlus()) makes no difference
console.log(a);

function bPlusPlus() {
  var x = b;
  b = b + 1;
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think that a clear explanation of implicit function returns would be helpful here.  b++ is returning 1.  ++b is returning 2, and that is what is put into the parentheses, correct?  But in either case, in subsequent statements, b is now equal to 2.

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting way to look at it. Sure, you can think of it that way too, but what's put into parentheses is the original value 1, not 2 (although neither case will make any difference). The body of the implicit function is similar to T.J.'s explanation. See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand the second example.  `b` is assigned to `a`, then incremented to `2`.

Not quite. Leaving out some details, it's:

1. Read the value of `b` (`1`) and set it aside.
2. Increment `b` to `2`.
3. Make the result of the `b++` expression the value that was set aside in Step #1 (the value `1`).
4. Assign that result from Step #3 to `a`.

...which is why the `()` don't make any difference. :-) The result of the `b++` expression just gets propagated as the result of the grouping operator (`()`).

Details in [the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-postfix-increment-operator).

Comment: Thank you for the answers! Might it also be accurate to say that (b++) evaluates to b++ ?? (Rather than how I was reading it...that the parentheses were forcing b++ to actually return the value of 2) ??

Comment: @LisaFriedrichsen: Yes, exactly. When you have the grouping operator around a single expression, the result of the grouping operator is always the result of that expression. In your case, the `b++` is the only expression in the entire right-hand side, so the `()` have no effect (whereas -- as I know you know, from the question -- sometimes `()` can matter, such as `a = (b + 2) * 10`). :-)

Comment: (Actually, at the top level, the grouping operator is always around a single expression. :-) But you get what I'm saying...)